# Offset when inserting Svg group into Svg file

Tags: svg

I have the Main.svg and the Template.svg files.

I want to programmatically insert Template.svg into Main.svg.
For this:

1. In Inskape I place the Template in a specific place and remember the coordinates
2. In Template.svg - set the specified coordinates
3. After the programmatically insertion, I get the Template offset from the position at which it should be located (-25.1632)

What could be the problem? The coordinates of the template inserted into Inskape and the coordinates of the template inserted programmatically match. Where is my mistake?

1. In Inskape:

[image]

Main.svg

```
<svg width="210mm" height="148mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 148" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g fill="none" stroke="#000">
  <path d="m4.3752 45.005h197.92" stroke-width="2.0845"/>
  <path d="m43.631 44.417 5.63e-4 -1.1146 0.0074-11.603" stroke-width=".81503"/>
  <path d="m59.98 67.884 5.6e-4 -1.9765 7e-3 -20.575" stroke-width="1.0815"/>
  <path d="m10.497 107.41h88.438" stroke-width="1.3934"/>
  <path d="m58.872 107.49 2e-3 -0.59044 0.024-6.1464" stroke-width="1.0653"/>
  <path d="m90.583 113.94 2e-3 -0.59044 0.024-6.1464" stroke-width="1.0653"/>
 </g>
 <g fill="none" stroke="#000">
  <path d="m137.75 107.95 2e-3 -0.59045 0.024-6.1464" stroke-width="1.0653"/>
  <path d="m169.46 114.4 2e-3 -0.59044 0.024-6.1464" stroke-width="1.0653"/>
  <path d="m127.41 107.5h63.336" stroke-width="1.1792"/>
  <path d="m137.77 67.877 5.6e-4 -1.9765 7e-3 -20.575" stroke-width="1.0815"/>
  <path d="m101.25 44.632 5.7e-4 -1.1146 7e-3 -11.603" stroke-width=".81503"/>
  <path d="m178.71 43.825 5.7e-4 -1.1146 7e-3 -11.603" stroke-width=".81503"/>
 </g> 

<!--<g> Place for the Template group </g>-->

</svg>
```

2. In Template change `translate(-10.664053 22.731272)` on `translate(65.438 9.0453)`
   Template.svg

```
<g transform="translate(-10.664053 22.731272)">
    <rect x="33.101" y="10.801" width="5.4464" height="7.1" fill="#fff"/>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#102027" stroke-linecap="round">
        <path d="m38.32 14.248h-5" stroke-width=".44444"/>
        <g stroke-width=".4">
            <path d="m35.82 5.6385v5" opacity=".98"/>
            <path d="m35.82 17.869v5"/>
            <path d="m37.07 10.74h-2.5"/>
            <path d="m37.07 17.818h-2.5"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

3. In Browser:
   [image]

In the browser I see following code. If the translates (*translate(65.438 9.0453)*) are equal, why are the two elements not the same?

```
<svg>
...
<!--Inskape-->
<g transform="translate(65.438 9.0453)">
    <rect x="33.101" y="10.801" width="5.4464" height="7.1" fill="#fff"/>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#102027" stroke-linecap="round">
        <path d="m38.32 14.248h-5" stroke-width=".44444"/>
        <g stroke-width=".4">
            <path d="m35.82 5.6385v5" opacity=".98"/>
            <path d="m35.82 17.869v5"/>
            <path d="m37.07 10.74h-2.5"/>
            <path d="m37.07 17.818h-2.5"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>

<!--programmatically insert-->
<g transform="translate(65.438 9.0453)">
    <rect x="7.9378" y="10.801" width="5.4464" height="7.1" fill="#fff"/>
    <g fill="none" stroke="#102027" stroke-linecap="round">
        <path d="m13.156 14.248h-5 " stroke-width=".4"/>                
        <g stroke-width=".4">
            <path d="m10.656 5.6385v5" opacity=".98"/>
            <path d="m10.656 17.869v5"/>
            <path d="m11.906 10.74h-2.5"/>
            <path d="m11.906 17.818h-2.5"/>
        </g>
        <title></title>
    </g>
</g>

</svg>
```

Comment: Because the shapes inside are not in the same place e.g. rect x="33.101" vs rect x="7.9378"

Comment: Robert, so when I programmatically insert, should I also take into account the arrangement of forms in the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that there was no offset, it was necessary to place all the elements on one canvas. When copying elements from other canvases - there will be an offset.

Thanks Robert Longson for the tip.